# Turning on Flying Saucer java.util.logging Output

Tags: itext, flying-saucer, java.util.logging

I'm compiling a PDF using iText and Flying Saucer, and unfortunately, I can't seem to get any output from Flying Saucer when compiling. I'd really like to be able to see what's going on internally so as to be able to debug the current problem I'm facing.

How can I turn on java.util.logging for Flying Saucer? I'm currently using SLF4J/Logback.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it:

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("xr.util-logging.loggingEnabled", "true");
XRLog.setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: How does this work with your SLF4j/Logback setup? `XRLog` uses `JDKXRLogger` logger by default which is JDK logging unfortunately.

Comment: @Tvaroh When using SLF4j/Logback you can use `System.getProperties().setProperty("xr.util-logging.handlers", "org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler");` (or run your application with  `-Dxr.util-logging.loggingEnabled=true -Dxr.util-logging.handlers=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler`). See http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html or http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j Also see https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-core/src/main/resources/resources/conf/xhtmlrenderer.conf for info about `xr.util-logging.handlers`

Comment: Looks like only the first line is needed? I got the logging to work with only that one. (Although I was not using the PDF generation but using the Swing component, and without dedicated logging library)