# Flying Saucer and CSS

Tags: css, ssl, https, keystore, flying-saucer

When using flying saucer to convert to xhtml to PDF, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
            at  java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
            at  java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
            at  java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
            at  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
            at  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
            at  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
            at  java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.zzRefill(Lexer.java:1634) 
             at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.yylex(Lexer.java:1865)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.next(CSSParser.java:1778) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.la(CSSParser.java:1790) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.stylesheet(CSSParser.java:157) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.parseStylesheet(CSSParser.java:87) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:78) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:95) 
atorg.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.getStylesheet(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:174) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.readAndParseAll(StyleReference.java:123) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.setDocumentContext(StyleReference.java:107) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:175) 
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:142)
```

I was able to view the content of the css file through the link: https ://.../file.css and I have create a keystore and certificate in JBOSS server and made sure ssl.conf is pointing to them (redhat). It seems there is an issue maybe with https, but have no idea how to tackle this. Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Thanks,
--Abdul

Comment: Without some code it's really hard to say where the problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure which code to post because it seems like this is a known issue, but no one has a solution for it yet. I was able to view the css file that's in my .ear file through the link directly, but when I render the PDF, it's not able to get the css file (even though it's included) and the styling of the PDF doesn't show. This works fine in different environments except one. That's why it seems like an environment related issue than code.

Comment: Did you pass the CSS path as URI? I had this issue once too, but I guess it was causes by a syntax error in html. Can you check (and maybe "clean") your input?

Answer (score 4):

It's too late, but someone else may found it useful. Here's how I solved my issue:

1. Turned on the Logging ([Turning on Flying Saucer java.util.logging Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729147/turning-on-flying-saucer-java-util-logging-output))

   ```
   System.getProperties().setProperty("xr.util-logging.loggingEnabled", "true");
   XRLog.setLoggingEnabled(true);
   ```
2. Read the org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent logs for

   public String resolveURI (String uri){
     /**/
     }

(If you can remote debug it/run JBoss locally - put a breakpoint there and you'll see all the font/resource/css loading)

In my case it turned out the baseURL is wrong for the renderer. You can pass it to renderer while parsing document.

```
renderer.setDocumentFromString(generatedHtml, getBaseUrl());
```

And to get the valid baseURL on my env I've used:

```
"jndi:"+servletContext.getResource("/").getPath()
```

(turned out you actually can access static files in the deployed war with this "jndi:" prefix.)